# How to define document height is changed in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem for showing a full size div over all of my HTML document. I've set the size of my div to my page width and height. and write this codes for resizing of document:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    sysSetOverlaySize(cDivOverlay);//cDivOverlay is my full size div
});
```

when my browser window resize this function is called and set the new size of my div from the size of my page. but when tinymce increase my page height this function only called in FF. I want some action to define when document height is changed.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you not just set height and width to 100%?  Is this an absolutely positioned div?

Comment: Can you provide all your HTML/CSS/JS? Would make it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it in css with positioning:

```
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have any problems with top & left. I need to set new width and height when document size change.

Comment: Explain again what you're trying to accomplish. The CSS I posted is to create a div that always covers the entire page, even when the browser window is resized (provided it's not nested in another div with position set that is smaller than the entire page.) Based on your original post this is what I understood your goal to be.

Comment: Thanks. my problem was I'd set width and height in js and when document resized by hide and show divs, my div didn't cover the entire page. when I use your css It solved.